# Github logo for Stack Overflow on Google Developers page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, third-party

When I was browsing through [Google Developers (Google Glass)](https://developers.google.com/glass/) page I noticed a thing Stack Overflow is being represented by Github logo.

```
<img src="/site-assets/logo-github.svg" class="devsite-footer-promo-icon">
```

[image: Link to Stack Overflow with Github logo]

I already raised this issue in Google Forums [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/iz9Bme2x_C4;context-place=forum/sites) (*I cannot find link to post this issue directly to Google people*).

But I feel if  Stack Exchange developers put request to Google requesting this be changed the process will be done earlier.

**Update**

Finally they changed thanks for everyone who are part of it :)

Thanks to [Danny Miller](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303880/4234454).

[image]

Comment: Don't tell me they don't have Stack Overflow logo? Trying `logo-stackoverflow.svg` and `logo-so.svg` returning 404.

Comment: Are they allowed the logo?

Comment: They do have SO logo see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/)



`<img src="/site-assets/logo-stack-overflow.svg" class="devsite-footer-promo-icon">`

Comment: Shouldn't you be bugging them?

Comment: @Won't already did but the process will be quick if Team SO does.

Comment: I wish to listen from Down voter what's wrong in my approach??

Comment: You just listened to him.  This has absolutely nothing to do with SE.  It's Google's goof.

Comment: So for your query I already posted in google form's your downvote wasted.

Comment: Like I said to Anna, Google are just too big to care. Stack Exchange can't force them to fix their bugs.

Comment: Noting can be impossible if we try at least now someone make my forums question bump and will make it active. @ShadowWizard

Comment: @dh47 but you should bump it on Google's forums, here you can offer 10000 reps, but nobody is able to do anything, that's my  point.

Comment: @ShadowWizard for bumping there I should first bump here.

Comment: Not sure why, anyway I've voted up your Google forum post and posted a reply, dunno if it bumps the thread though. Keeping in mind I got a notification for my own reply, I don't put much hopes into their software. :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you already put in a request to change it, I don't think we need to. Just make sure you follow whatever issue-reporting guidelines the Google Developers site/page has in place.

I added a comment on your thread with a link to our [logos](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos). Hope that helps.

**Update:** [Danny Miller to the rescue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303880/105971). (The logo has been corrected.)

Comment: Thanks for that but they actually have one we can see it on other [pages](https://developers.google.com/maps/) .

Comment: @dh47 Cool. Sounds like the odds of them fixing this one are pretty good, then. :)

Comment: Personally I don't think they will bother to fix it. Google is way too big to care about small things like that.

Comment: Also, maybe related, they don't have a sponsored logo picture [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gdk) - they surely have a mess when it comes to logos.

Comment: The request that OP put is categorically the wrong place. It's for Google Sites, and it is a 100% community help forum with no official Googlers lurking.

Comment: @gladoscc actually, google staff to look there - I've seen a few questions answered by them.

Comment: @Tim 0.000001% or 0.0001% of the questions? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Probably - just the ones I've seen which are of course the popular ones.

Comment: @gladoscc I didn't find other place to post if you can find please post that.

Comment: It's been more than two months, and the issue is still there. Do you think it's worth trying to escalate? (No clue what the escalation path would be.)

Comment: @ruakh I agree, it's been over three months now, and this still hasn't been changed.

Comment: @Anna, small tip: do not write '*Our* logos...' but 'The StackOverflow logos...' At first I thought someone from Google had answered with a completely irrelevant remark ;-)

Comment: @Anna, it's cute that you think a normal person can affect anything at Google, but as you can see by the absence of any activity in the last three months, that's not gonna happen. So unless you'll send in an official request coming from Stack Exchange the company, this will not get fixed. The Google Forums are clearly not read by anyone at Google.

Comment: I don't see why no action was taken by Stack Exchange to protect their brand when this was originally reported. The original poster may have had better luck using the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of every page, but this is a blatant violation of the Trademark guidance and should have been dealt with. "***Do not** use our logo in a way that confuses our brand with another brand.*"

Comment: @TinyGiant Technically, they're using someone else's logo, so our trademark guidance doesn't apply. ;)

Comment: I was hoping Google would respond, but guess not. I don't know if we have a special channel or anything to reach someone who can make the change, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Ok, so Stack Exchange will approve of me using their name to confuse the Stack Exchange brand with another brand, just not their logo? That seems more like an editors oversight than an intended technicality.

Comment: All - It can be *incredibly* difficult to track down the person that actually needs to see this kind of thing in order for anyone to do anything about it, but I'm going to see what I can do.

Comment: Why not ask Jon Skeet if he has someone in his back channel? He does work there and is somewhat active here.

Comment: This is also being discussed here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303804/google-is-mixing-github-and-stack-overflow

Comment: @Anna So [this would be acceptable?](http://i.imgur.com/haubjpU.png)

Comment: @AnnaLear granted that IANAL, but wouldn't using the ***wrong*** trademark be something actionable? If I was to put a Nike Swoosh above the word 'Adidas', I'm fairly certain that both Nike and Adidas would have trademark issue with me. Does trademark guidance not have an implicit "actually use our trademark rather than a trademark for another company"?

Comment: @MichaelT I imagine it would be actionable. I was just making a joke... and a bad one at that.

Comment: @AnnaLear Fair 'nuff... though this does bring up the question of "why not get your lawyer to send their lawyer a 'hey, by the way, you've got two bits of trademark messup going on in this page... could you fix it before I have to send anything more formal?'"

Comment: @MichaelT No need - it's getting handled without threatening legal actions.

Comment: @AnnaLear its more of a "things should be handled with the level and promptness."  As you are well aware, it is very difficult for a company to respond to every feature and bug posted in their forum / messaging / site. Many of these will go responded to. If there was some random 1 rep user asking about a trademark or copyright infringement in a random question, it may be ignored or get a "if you want us to remove or fix this, fill out the proper paperwork and address it to the proper channel." Google is no different. Developer posts have much lower priority than lawyer emails.

Comment: Ad Sales FTW! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303804/google-is-mixing-github-and-stack-overflow/303880#303880